# Alternative symbols to represent Valentine's Day?

Tags: icon, symbolism

Anyone have ideas other than heart shapes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the right combination of colors immediately makes me think of valentine's day. I'd say a pink ribbon/stripe through a rich red background is a subtle but effective reminder.

Answer (score 3):

You may explore direct references to Love:

- Cupid as an angel with a bow, son of Venus
- Venus (goddess of Love)
- a couple kissing

Or maybe something less direct:

- a love letter
- vine
- red roses

Answer (score 1):

If it is about symbols, I think I'd go for something like a candy heart or something neat.

The heart symbol is widely accepted as symbol for love – mostly in terms of innocent, deep and heartfelt sympathy.

In case you aim to be unique with your choice of a iconographic symbol; don't choose something unusual for the sake of being unusual.

Perhaps, if you have a specific context, it can be appropriate to choose something special, but that should be reflected carefully.

Lets say, you have a site about lashes-fetish or stuff – perhaps it'd do better to depict some lingerie arranged as a heart, or have black leather strings forming a heart.

Otherwise, if it is just a random context (what is yours?), I'd stick with the well-established standards.

Comment: the context in this case is for a tiling background image to a website. I often change it (or to be more exact, let PHP change it) when an event comes up. At the moment I'm using snowflakes, only simple vector lines, and also only two colors, different shades of grey. Reason I didnt want to use heart is because it may be a bit to mushy and undiscrete if it's tiled

Answer (score 0):

How about a lipstick'ish kiss-mouth shape?

Answer (score 0):

Rose blades spread out on a soft pink background.

Answer (score 0):

Chocolate could fit in to valentines day together with other symbols. A box of chocolates is quite usual as a present in valentines day.